# Deleting expired SQL server database backup file on data domain using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am backing up the database on data domain however I'll have to delete an expired backup using following command. It's an emc databoost agent app for Microsoft sql server.

I am trying to convert the command into powershell so I can run the command to delete expired backups from multiple clients in a loop. That way I can avoid running the command on each individual client.

I created following script and `$clientname` is hardcoded, but I would like to pass multiple server names as `$clientname` in loop.

```
$FileExe = "C:\..\bin\ddbmexptool.exe"
$dbtype = "mssql"
$dduser = "DDBOOST_USER=dduser"
$ddhostpath = "DEVICE_PATH=DDHOSTMSSQL"
$devicehostname = "DEVICE_HOST=ddhost.domain.com"
$clientname = "CLIENT=server1.domain.com"

& $FileExe -n $dbtype -a $dduser -a $ddhostpath -a $ddhostpath -a $devicehostname -a $clientname -b "6 weeks ago" -e "2 weeks ago"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$FileExe = "C:\..\bin\ddbmexptool.exe"
$dbtype = "mssql"
$dduser = "DDBOOST_USER=dduser"
$ddhostpath = "DEVICE_PATH=DDHOSTMSSQL"
$devicehostname = "DEVICE_HOST=ddhost.domain.com"
$servers = "server1","server2","server3"

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  $clientname = "CLIENT=$server.domain.com"
  & $FileExe -n $dbtype -a $dduser -a $ddhostpath -a $ddhostpath -a $devicehostname -a $clientname -b "6 weeks ago" -e "2 weeks ago"   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked although it does return file sets before deleting actual file, it also throws following error     :-    ddbmexptool.exe : Setting default operation display information for savesets by savetime range.
At D:\...\ddboostscript2.ps1:12 char:3
+   & $FileExe -n $dbtype -a $dduser -a $ddhostpath -a $ddhostpath -a $ ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Setting default...savetime range.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`